# Setting up putty key

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, putty

really hope you can help me here, i have a 12.04 server and a linux pc at home which i set up ssh keygen for with no problems, i want to now gain laptop entry to the server [win7] using putty, i have made the private key and public one, copy and pasted the public one to a new file called authorized_keys2 and moved that file into .ssh/authorized_keys .. before i did that i sudo chmod 600 authorized_keys2

Then put the key private key into pageant started putty put host name in etc, and its not working, i know or feel i missing permission here or something clearly not set right, anyone share any thoughts on this?
After 3 failed login,s i get locked out by Fail2ban, which i happy with, its working. lol
Or at least i hope thats all thats wrong, at the minute i cant gain entry, will wait 10 mins before trying , been reading a lot on how to do this, but no one says it clearly for using a second key through putty.
Thanks people, look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to generate a key using PuTTYgen, because PuTTY uses a different key format.

You can also convert an existing OpenSSH format key. See [here](https://www.virag.si/2010/02/convert-openssh-private-key-to-putty-private-key-for-github/).

I suggest to do the first approach. You should *never* have to move private keys around, unless you're taking backups, in my opinion.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, yea i made the keys using puttygen, and have the public key on usb and loaded into the server /etc/known_hosts ..  no work, i even tried putting into /ssh/authotized_keys, no work.. i then made a new file called authorized_keys2 and chmod 600, then mv to /ssh/authotized_keys, this of course was a bad move, it over ride the key in there and locked me out of server, after 2 hours work i got it removed and new key set set up using keygen on my tower pc, back to where i started now. Where does the public key go that puttygen made? I lost on this.

Comment: @jamjam Make sure you export the *public* key in OpenSSH format and put this in `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Recursively set permissions correct: `chown -R user:user /home/user/.ssh` and `chmod -R go-rwx /home/user/.ssh`. OpenSSH server is quite picky on this. Also make sure to check `var/log/auth.log` for errors on this level.

Comment: Please remember this is the second key, first key works fine and sits in .ssh/authorized_keys  i not do this..   chmod -R jamjam:jamjam go-rwx~/.ssh    i have  however chmod -R jamjam:jamjam .ssh   chmod 700 .ssh   chmod 600 .shh/authorized_keys and my pc tower key works fine, please if we could start with where the key goes, do i have to put it into .ssh/authorized_keys and then set the permission up right by doing chmod -R go-rwx /home/user/.ssh??  Thanks for helping me hey, need it. lol

Comment: Back again, checked permission on the .ssh/  i got  drwx------